# Atualizar vários banco de dados usando code first sem usar console

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, code-first

Boa tarde, galera.

Tenho uma aplicação que cada cliente possui seu banco de dados e estou usando o code first. Para atualizar estou sempre rodando na mão o comando `update-database -force` no *package console* para cada banco de dados do cliente. Alguém sabe uma forma de automatizar esse processo? Fiz uma pesquisa e encontrei esse link [entity-framework-code-first-migration-to-multiple-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907826/entity-framework-code-first-migration-to-multiple-database), contudo ocorre erro ao executar o comando update.

Desejo ter algum script para atualizar todos os banco de dados de forma automática, ou seja um tenho um contexto que possui mais de um database no `web.config`.

O erro que ocorreu é o seguinte:

> Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss. Set AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed to 'true' on your DbMigrationsConfiguration to allow application of automatic migrations even if they might cause data loss. Alternately, use Update-Database with the '-Force' option, or scaffold an explicit migration.

Comment: Qual erro ocorreu?

Comment: Segue o erro @VictorStafusa

Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss. Set AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed to 'true' on your DbMigrationsConfiguration to allow application of automatic migrations even if they might cause data loss. Alternately, use Update-Database with the '-Force' option, or scaffold an explicit migration.]

Comment: *Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss.* - Tem certeza que o tamanho dos campos varchar estão corretos e que não há nenhuma coluna ou tabela faltando?

Comment: update-database -force no console funciona, então não é esse o problema.

Comment: E sem o -force?

Comment: Funciona também.

Comment: Bem, a mensagem de erro está dizendo que há algum lugar onde não funciona sem o `-force`, e é por isso que ele não faz. E o motivo pelo qual ele não faz é porque algum dado acabaria sendo perdido em algum lugar. Assim sendo, sugiro você tentar descobrir quais são os registros e colunas que poderiam causar alguma perda de dados na migração e o porquê. O `-force` serve para ele passar por cima disso tudo e não se importar caso de fato vá ocorrer alguma perda de dados (o que pode ser algo perigoso).

Comment: e como poderia descobrir isso? Tens alguma ideia? Usando o AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed  = true funciona, mais fiquei preocupado com essa questão de perca de dados

Comment: Não, não sei. Mas com isso, acho que a sua pergunta já ficou mais esclarecida. Vou votar para reabrir.

Comment: @VictorStafusa será que é melhor eu fazer uma nova pergunta?

Comment: Não, não faça uma nova pergunta. Ela acabaria sendo fechada como duplicata desta. Só tem que arrumar mais quatro pessoas para reabrir, o que não é lá muito difícil e vou te ajudar com isso.

Answer (score 2):

Defina o seguinte no seu arquivo de configuração (`Web.config`):

```xml
<configuration>
  ...
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
    <contexts>
      <context type="MeuSistema.Models.MeuSistemaContext, MeuSistema">
        <databaseInitializer type="System.Data.Entity.MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion`2[[MeuSistema.Models.MeuSistemaContext, MeuSistema], [MeuSistema.Migrations.Configuration, MeuSistema]], EntityFramework, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="DefaultConnection" />
          </parameters>
        </databaseInitializer>
      </context>
    </contexts>
  </entityFramework>
  ...
</configuration>
```

Ao publicar seu projeto, o migrador executa automaticamente ao acessar o banco de dados pela primeira vez após a publicação.

---

**EDIT**

Esta mensagem:

> Automatic migration was not applied because it would result in data loss.

É um mecanismo de proteção do Entity Framework para mudanças em banco de dados que serão destrutivas, ou seja, que resultarão em perda de dados de tabelas envolvidas.

Antes de executar quaisquer *Migrations*, faça um backup do seu banco de dados.

O correto, quando isto ocorre, é reiniciar o histórico de migrações (tabela `__MigrationHistory`), apagando todas as *Migrations* e gerando uma nova *Migration* inicial. Depois disso, restaurar os dados do backup no banco.

Agora, se a integridade dos dados não for um problema, você pode definir, em `Migrations/Configuration.cs`, a seguinte construção:

```cs
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
```

Isto permitirá às suas *Migrations* mudanças destrutivas no *Schema*. Não recomendo este tipo de configuração para o ambiente de produção do seu sistema.

Comment: O que você acha de reabrirmos a pergunta?

Comment: Não sei nem por que foi fechada.